# Efficient algorithm to find master element in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find out whether a given array A containing N integers has a "master element". The master element of this array is an element that appears more than n/2 times in the array.

For example:

- the array `A={5,1,3,5,5}` has a master element (in this case 5).
- the array `A={5,1,2,3,3}` doesn’t have a master element.

Below is my code so far.

I'd like to know what is the most efficient algorithm to solve this problem?

The algorithm need to return `true` if array has a master element and return `false` if it does not have master element.

```
boolean masterElement(int[] a) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean check = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length/2; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) { 
                count++;
            }
        } 
        if (count >= a.length/2) {
            check = true;
            break;
        }
        count = 0;
    }
    return check;
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: why dont you try it yourself first

Comment: Apologies for my math knowledge but does that mean the master element is the one which is mentioned 3 or more times in the array?

Comment: @Draken, According to the definition above, **more than n/2** means 
 `{1,1,2,2}` have no master element

Comment: I already posted my code, It's not important to determine number of master element, just  has or does not has master element.

Comment: I want to know is there another way to solve this problem, but more efficient than my way? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 8, you could use `Streams` and `Collectors` like this:

```
    int[] a = {5,1,3,5,5}; 
    final int n=a.length;
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> x = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i->i));
    // System.out.println(x); // {1=[1], 3=[3], 5=[5, 5, 5]}
    x.forEach((k,v)->{
        if(v.size()>n/2) System.out.println(k); // Check whether you need > or >=
    });
```

Please look at the explanations in comments in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean masterElement(int[] a) {
    int half = a.length / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length && count <= half; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > half) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```